# Software for web design

Tags: 16.04, software-installation, software-recommendation, websites, web-development

I am looking for software that I could use for web design. I know one of my options would be gimp, but I am looking for anything that would work better than it.

edit: I need something like Photoshop for windows. I use Brackets for the coding part

Comment: I am afraid you need to narrow it down. Are you looking for a dreamwever- like application, a graphics editor or a plain html editor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Photoshop** alternatives are :-

- [Krita](https://krita.org/) is a raster graphics editor based on Qt 5 and the KDE Frameworks 5. Krita is designed to be a digital painting application. It has been influenced to some extent by software like Corel Painter and SAI. Krita packs with some key features different from most of its kind, including the ability to work with both bitmap and vector illustration.
- [MyPaint](http://mypaint.org/) is a free and open-source raster graphics editor for digital painters with a focus on painting rather than image manipulation or post processing. MyPaint is available for Microsoft Windows, OS X, and Linux. It is in some ways similar to Corel Painter.
- [Pinta](https://pinta-project.com/pintaproject/pinta/) is a free, open source program for drawing and image editing. Its goal is to provide users with a simple yet powerful way to draw and manipulate images on Linux, Mac, Windows, and *BSD.
- [Inkscape](https://inkscape.org/) is a professional vector graphics editor for Windows, Mac OS X and Linux. It's free and open source.
- [Polarr Photo Editor](https://www.polarr.co/linux-electron?platform=polarr&label=homepage_website) is an ideal photo editor for photographers. It offers advanced auto-enhance tools and sophisticated filters to edit every detail of your photo.

For coding part, I recommend :-

1. [Sublime Text](https://www.sublimetext.com/) is a proprietary cross-platform source code editor with a Python application programming interface (API). It natively supports many programming languages and markup languages, and its functionality can be extended by users with plugins, typically community-built and maintained under free-software licenses.
   It is recommended if you want a very fast code editor.
2. [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/) is a free and open-source code editor developed by Microsoft for Windows, Linux and macOS. It includes support for debugging, embedded Git control, syntax highlighting, intelligent code completion, snippets, and code refactoring.
   It is based on **Electron** (formerly known as Atom Shell), a framework that enables cross-platform desktop applications using Chromium and Node.js. It is great for Javascript development.
3. [Atom](https://atom.io/) is a free and open-source text and source code editor for OS X, Linux, and Windows with support for plug-ins written in Node.js, and embedded Git Control, developed by GitHub. Atom is a desktop application built using web technologies. Atom, like Visual Studio Code, is based on **Electron** . It is written in CoffeeScript and Less. It can also be used as an integrated development environment (IDE). Its developers call it **A hackable text editor for the 21st Century**.
4. [Brackets](http://brackets.io/) is an open-source editor written in HTML, CSS, and JavaScript with a primary focus on Web Development. It was created by Adobe Systems, licensed under the MIT License, and is currently maintained on GitHub. Brackets is available for cross-platform download on Mac, Windows, and Linux.
5. [Geany](http://www.geany.org/) is a text editor using the GTK+ toolkit with basic features of an integrated development environment. It was developed to provide a small and fast IDE, which has only a few dependencies from other packages. It supports many filetypes and has some nice features. It is recommended if you want a small and fast IDE that has built-in support for major languages so that you don't have to customise it to fit your needs.

NOTE: Visual Studio Code, Atom & Brackets are good code editors but they aren't as fast as Sublime Text till now. But one great advantage of them over Sublime Text is that they are open-source.

Comment: You recommended 5 text editors to code. Can a person use 5 text editors for work seriously?

Comment: @Anwar I just gave the list of good code editors out there. You can choose any one of them. Each has its pros and cons. Like if you want very fast code editor, choose Sublime Text. If you want an open-source product, choose Atom, Visual Studio Code or Brackets. If you don't want to do customisation in your development environment to suit your needs and want an IDE that has built-in all the basic support of major languages, choose Geany.

Answer (score 1):

If you have simple graphics to make, an image editor that produces SVG produces small image sizes.

Inkscape is one such program.

You should investigate if this is an option for you, using SVG.

I use Kate for my programming needs - html and programming in C. It will pay in the end to learn the way HTML and CSS is written if you have not already done so. A simple text editor like Kate allows you to focus on the structure of what is written instead of having to learn the specifics of an IDE.

Answer (score 0):

[Atom](https://atom.io) and [Sublime Text](https://www.sublimetext.com) are two of the most popular editors.

Comment: i edited my question
i will try out atom though

Comment: Probably this (http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/5-photoshop-alternatives-can-run-linux/) helps you? Please do not forget to upvote and/or accept my answer, if it helped you.